# Move a folder if a file exist, the check should perform in multiple directories

Tags: batch-file

I want a batch file to check for a certain files in a folder and all of its subdirectories and if that file is found I want to copy the folder in which the file sits.

How can I achieve it? Can anyone help?

Comment: Sure, I can write you a script, that will be $250.... Stack overflow is not a "request free scripts" forum. I suggest you read [how to ask](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjh65jGsfveAhUkI8AKHellCEEQFjAAegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-ask&usg=AOvVaw00xttYhbqoB7L7CXC05R8r) and [mcve](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwilw67nsfveAhUmJcAKHdpSDKAQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fmcve&usg=AOvVaw0S639LB-n61Tf1wySi7YAL)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```bat
@echo off
for /R "full_path_to_folder_with_subfolders" %%A IN (filename_you_want_to_check) do (
copy %%~FA "full_path_you_want_file_to_be_copied"
)
```

**NOTES:**

- `full_path_to_folder_with_subfolders` should be replaced with the **FULL PATH** of folder which contains the subfolders in which you want to search the certain files.
- `filename_you_want_to_check` is only **ONE** certain file you want **EXCEPT** if your files have a common suffix, for example you have files `a1.txt` and `a2.txt` (**ONLY IF** these files will be copied in the same location) replace `filename_you_want_to_check` with `a*.txt`.
- `full_path_you_want_file_to_be_copied` is the **FULL PATH** where your certain files (`filename_you_want_to_check`) should be copied.

Hope this helps!